# Spring i18n question

Tags: spring

I have a question using Spring i18n. Can i pass parameters to i18ned messages from other message codes.

For eg.

```
YesKey=Yes
NoKey=No

Message1=This is {YesKey} 
Message2=This is {NoKey}
```

Is there any alternative to this if i cann't implement .

Answer (score 2):

As fare I know it is not possible use a message in an other message simply by using there name. -- This is not a limitation of spring, it is a limitation of `java.text.MessageFormat`.

But what you can do is this:

message.properties:

```
YesKey=Yes
NoKey=No

Message1=This is {0} 
Message2=This is {0}
```

java code

```
 MessageSource messageSource =...
 String param = messageSource.getMessage("YesKey",
                      new Object[0], Locale.English);
 String message = messageSource.getMessage("Message1",
                      new Object[]{param}, Locale.English);
```

or in jsp(x):

```
 <spring:message var="param" code="YesKey" />
 <spring:message var="message" code="Message1" arguments="${param}" />
```